# How do I print repeated values from an array using binary search java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, netbeans

Hi I am creating a program which has two parallel arrays (studentNum & grades) in the searchMark method I prompt the user too enter a grade they want to find. The program then uses binary search to find the value then check if any other students have it. and then all the student numbers along with their grade get printed out in the output screen. The program/code will end immediately after locating the first instance of the target in the array, I have included a picture of what my output is and what the output should look like.

```
       // Binary Search
    int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;
    int middleIndex;
    int shiftPlus = 0;
    int shiftMinus = grade.length-1;
    int midValue = 0;

    while (startIndex <= endIndex) {
        
        middleIndex = (startIndex+endIndex)/2;
        
        if (grade[middleIndex] == target) {
            midValue = grade[middleIndex];
            System.out.println("student #" + student[middleIndex] 
            + " has a correct count of " + target);
            break;
        }
        else if (grade[middleIndex] > target)
            endIndex = middleIndex-1;
        
        else if (grade[middleIndex] < target)
            startIndex = middleIndex + 1;

    }  
    
    boolean aboveMid = true, belowMid = true; // for while loops to stop/start
    
    while (shiftPlus <= midValue && aboveMid == true) {
        shiftPlus += 1; // starts at 0 and moves 1 up each loop            
        if(grade[shiftPlus] == target && shiftPlus <= midValue) 
        {
            System.out.println("student #" + student[shiftPlus] 
            + " has a correct count of " + target);
        }
        else
            belowMid = false;          
    }
    
    while (shiftMinus >= midValue && belowMid == true) {
        shiftMinus -= 1; // subtract one from end
        if(grade[shiftMinus] == target && shiftMinus <= midValue) 
        {
            System.out.println("student #" + student[shiftMinus] 
            + " has a correct count of " + target);
        } 
        else
            aboveMid = false;            
    }
}
```

The output of this code is when I enter any  number but 3:

what mark would you like to search for?
6
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

However if I enter the number '3'
what mark would you like to search for?
3
student #2 has a correct count of 3
student #3 has a correct count of 3

Comment: *Unfortunately I keep failing at getting it to search for other students with the same mark.* Unfortunately that isnt a problem description we could help with. Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: How does it look now? I am quite new to this platform I understand it can be annoying to have people like me adding so much clutter

Comment: Please dont use screenshots. Those should be your last resort. Ensure that your question contains the input you are working with, and the output as **text**.

Comment: will do that from now on when I have questions. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Binary search is built into java (`Arrays.binarySearch`), it's a mistake to write that yourself. Unless, of course, this is homework and writing a binary search algorithm was the homework.

Note that binary search **requires that your input array is sorted**. Running binsearch on an unsorted input produces garbage. As in, no errors, just.. wrong answers result. That's a fundamental property of binary search.

Think about your algorithm for a second: Let's say **all** the students scored 6 points. Then clearly, the intent is for you to print out **all** the students.

Your code will print in only two places. Those two places are inside a for loop, and it for-loops X amount of times, where X is `target - shiftPlus'. Your code is not complete (shiftPlus is not defined anywhere), but clearly then if 'target' changes, the number of prints changes. Which proves that this makes no sense: If you're looking for students with score 7, and they all have a score of 7, you'd print one more or one less vs the scenario where you're looking for score 6 and they all scored 6? Nope, that can't be right. Therefore 'target' should not be a part of a loop count in the first place, somewhere along the line in designing this algorithm you've made a wrong turn.

The point of this part of the algorithm is to look 'around' the index your binary search found, because there might be more than one student with the intended score, and if there are more than 1, they'll be immediately adjacent to your 'hit'.

One key clue is that you have no idea how many hits there might be until you get there, so **a for loop that counts** is right out. Maybe a `while` is more appropriate? A `for` can work too, but some index lookup then needs to be part of the terminating condition (in between the two `;` inside the for).

Let's say the scores are: [4,6,6,6,7,8], and your binsearch happened to stumble upon the **first** of the 3 `6` scores. In other words, the result of the binary search is: There is a match at index = 1.

You want to first 'look down' at the 4 (so, -1 relative to your found index: index = 0), look up the score at index 0 which is `4`, realize 4 isn't 6, and not print anything, and furthermore, stop looking any further downwards.

Then you want to 'look up', starting at your own index (index = 1), fetch the score at that index (`6`), realize that is in fact the target index, so print that student and then keep going: add 1 to your index (index = 2 now) and repeat the algorithm. this 'hits' again, prints another student, increments the index, hits a third time, increments index to 4, fetches the score at index 4 (`7`), now fails, so doesn't print anything and will not continue looking. Then you also need to program in the edge case of when there aren't any further indices to look at. Imagine the input was `[4,6,6,6]`, you don't want the program to crash out with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your algorithm keeps going further down the list until it finds a number that isn't 6.

I'm not going to just dump a fully functioning program in here, as clearly this is homework, and the aim is for you to learn and understand java, not to learn and understand the function of the CTRL/CMD+C and CTRL/CMD+V keys :)

Comment: Hi thank your for the help, I got it working again but only when I enter the target value of 3. When the target value entered is 3 it prints both students who got the score 3. however if I say enter 6, it just says build completed. btw thank you for not posting the code I would rather struggle then be given the answer. anyway I updated the code if you could provide some additional guidelines and critiques, that would be great!

Comment: @RayaanKhan are your inputs sorted?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you find the item you were looking for and it's in the index `idx` so you can iterate while its boundaries are equal to arr[idx]

```
leftidx = idx-1;
while(arr[leftidx]==arr[idx]{
   System.out.println(arr[leftidx]);
   lefidx--;
}
rightidx = idx+1;
while(arr[rightidx]==arr[idx]{
   System.out.println(arr[rightidx]);
   rightidx--;
}
```